# Get posts with n latest comments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, left-join, mongoose-populate

So this is a common problem, getting posts with comments, which i can't seem to solve in MongoDB, unlike in MySQL which is easily solved with `left-join`.

#### Problem:

I would like to fetch the **latest 8 posts** with **2 recent comments** on each post in MongoDB

- I don't want to restructure the post data to contain a list of the matching comment ids because i will expect thousands of comments in the future.
- I really don't want to resort to fetching the posts, then performing 8 separate queries using the post id to find the 2 latest comments. (*although i guess is the next best solution*)
- I have tried setting `postSchema.virtual('comments', ..)` and then when performing the query, populating by using `Post.find(..).populate('comments', options: {limit: 2})`, but unfortunately limit returns [inconsistent results](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4321).

#### Data:

```
Post:
{ body: "post1" }
{ body: "post2" }
{ body: "post3" }
...
{ body: "post8" }

Comment:
{ post_id: 1, message: "comment1" }
{ post_id: 2, message: "comment2" }
{ post_id: 2, message: "comment3" }
{ post_id: 3, message: "comment4" }
```

*All documents have a `date` field, but is removed due to brevity*

#### Expected result:

```
{ 
  body:"post1", 
  comments: [
    { post_id: 1, message: "comment1" }
  ]
}
{ 
  body:"post2", 
  comments: [
    { post_id: 2, message: "comment2" },
    { post_id: 2, message: "comment3" }
  ]
}
{ 
  body:"post3", 
  comments: [
    { post_id: 3, message: "comment4" }
  ]
}
...
```

Comment: How do you define that something is "recent" ? Do you have any date fields in both collections ?

Comment: Yeah just a simple `date` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB 3.6 or higher you can use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to "join" posts with comments and take 2 most recent ones (using [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html))

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { date: -1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 8
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "comments",
            let: { postId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$postId", "$post_id" ] } } },
                { $sort: { date: -1 } },
                { $limit: 2 }
            ],
            as: "comments"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Wow, you made my Saturday! Most satisfying answer I have received in a while, works perfectly thank-you! Good to know about $lookup